# Aggregating filtered data in Excel/Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, excel-formula, spreadsheet

Say I have the following spreadsheet for personal budgeting:

```
| Date       | Category | Price  |
| ---------- |--------- | ------ |
| 01/09/2015 | coffee   |  $3.50 |
| 03/09/2015 | groceries| $12.00 |
| 05/09/2015 | tech     | $99.00 |
```

Now, *without adding any extra columns* I would like to be able to create and track spending across multiple categories.

For example I create a budget for food, that contains all groceries and coffee and I'd like to create a formula that will effectively be the following pseudocode:

`SUM('Price', WHERE('Category' IN ['coffee', 'groceries']))`

Now, what would be the actual formula to achieve that?

As a second priority, how could it be altered to show total spending on food in the last 7 or last 30 days?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match two or more categories at a time by using a formula like this:-

```
=SUMPRODUCT(C2:C4*(B2:B4={"coffee","groceries"}))
```

For the second part, you can add another condition

```
=SUMPRODUCT(C2:C4*(A2:A4>TODAY()-7)*(B2:B4={"coffee","groceries"}))
```

or

```
=SUMPRODUCT(C2:C4*(A2:A4>MAX(A2:A4)-7)*(B2:B4={"coffee","groceries"}))
```

depending whether you want to compare the date with today's date or the last date in your data.

[image]